# FCM token becomes invalid within 2 hours after it have updated

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have updated FCM token, send push notification without any problems. After 2 hours I'm trying to send push notification with same token, but it produces an error `messaging/registration-token-not-registered`. I have read reasons of this error and no one fits.

[image]

Could you tell where issue could be?